# Return an unparsed list of dictionaries in Zapier Code

Tags: python, json, webhooks, zapier

I have successfully created code that reads from my form trigger how many managers and members (arbitrary roles in a company) are in the form. Then it creates an array successfully that looks like this:

```
"managers": [
   {
      "full_name": “Manager One“,
      "email": “managerone@gmail.com”,
      "address": “111 Manager St“,
      "city_st_zip": “Manager, Texas 11111”
    }, 
   {
      "full_name": “Manager Two“,
      "email": “managertwo@gmail.com”,
      "address": “222 Manager St“,
      "city_st_zip": “Manager, Texas 22222”
    }
]
```

The code step works just great and I've confirmed it returns what I want. The issue is that I need to implant it into some JSON I'm formatting to send elsewhere via webhook. I was expecting the Code Step to have the blob of code ready to go for me to just insert into the Custom Webhook Request like:

```
{
      "name": “ABC Company”,
      "managers": [
       {
          "full_name": “Manager One“,
          "email": “managerone@gmail.com”,
          "address": “111 Manager St“,
          "city_st_zip": “Manager, Texas 11111”
        }, 
       {
          "full_name": “Manager Two“,
          "email": “managertwo@gmail.com”,
          "address": “222 Manager St“,
          "city_st_zip": “Manager, Texas 22222”
        }
      ],
      "members": [
        {
          "full_name": “Member One”,
          "email": “memberone@gmail.com”,
          "address": “111 Member St“,
          "city_st_zip": “Member, Texas 11111”
          "invested": 100,
          "stake": 50
        },
        {
          "full_name": “Member Two”,
          "email": “membertwo@gmail.com”,
          "address": “222 Member St”,
          "city_st_zip": “Member Texas 22222”
          "invested": 100,
          "stake": 50
        }
      ],
      "taxes_manager": “Taxes Manager“,
      "business_purpose": “make money“,
      "principal_office_street": “123 Main St”,
      "principal_office_city_st_zip": “Principal, Texas 78701“,
      "state": "TX",
  }
```

The problem is that Zapier parses the list of dictionaries into individual variables instead of just giving me the whole block of code as shown here

[image]

How do I insert the list of dictionaries into the JSON as I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. Great question!

You've got two main options:

1. Do the request in the code step itself. There are docs [here](https://zapier.com/help/code-python/#weather-json-api-call). This is great because functionality stats together and it's easy to troubleshoot
2. Instead of returning `managers`, return `{"payload": json.dumps(managers)}`, which will return a string instead of an object. We don't do any extra processing on strings, so you can use it in another step. **Note** that if you do this, the following step needs to be **Custom Request**, not POST (because the latter warns not to put raw JSON strings in there since we parse it again).

Both of these options have the same effect, though #2 will cost you an extra task on your usage. Depending how close to limits you are, this may or may not matter.

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!

Comment: Glad I could help! :)